# http connection in windows Phone (wp7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi i want to know to implement the basic Http connection mechanism in Wp 7.For eg,I want to parse rss feeds and display it in the application,how can i do it?

While refering some code sections of  Httpconnection in Wp7 ,i came across

3 lines

Line 1:

```
request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
```

Line 2:

```
void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)  
    { webRequest.BeginGetResponse(blahh...   }
```

Line 3:

```
void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult){ }
```

On these 3 lines ,So my Question is do we need everytime GetRequestStreamCallback,and then going for GetResponseCallback.Is this default mechanism based on C#?or else can we call the GetResponseCallback.Plz correct me ,if question seems absurd.

regards
Rakesh Shankar.P

Comment: If you mean async I/O, that is the standard for WP (Silverlight actually).

Comment: After asking 75 questions you should pay a little more attention to formatting. The (lack) of spaces and capitalization makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

The [BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) method starts an asynchronous request for a stream used to send data for the HttpWebRequest. The asynchronous callback method uses the EndGetRequestStream method to return the actual stream.

The [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) method starts an asynchronous request for a response from the Internet resource. The asynchronous callback method uses the EndGetResponse method to return the actual WebResponse.

MSDN documentation also says, " If you call the BeginGetRequestStream method, you must use the BeginGetResponse method to retrieve the response."

If you have any data to send in the request then you should use BeginGetRequestStream followed by BeginGetResponse. Otherwise you can directly call BeginGetResponse.

For any further clarification, have a look at the above links.